# Turning html into text with proper indentation in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

There is html text taken from a telegram.
**The HTML looks just like that, don't edit it:**

```
 <b>Процесс химчистки сидений:</b>

<b>1</b> - <i>Тщательно пропылесосить</i>

<b>2</b> - <i>Нанести химию и немного подождать, пока она поработает</i>
<i>
</i><b>3</b> - <i>Пройтись щеткой, чтобы поднять загрязнения</i>

<b>4</b> - <i>Тщательно прополоскать сидение экстрактором с подачей воды</i>
<i>
</i>#химчисткасалона #химчисткасидений
```

I need to use Beautifulsoup to turn it into such text. But using Beautifulsoup is optional, you can use any other library:

```
 Процесс химчистки сидений:

1 - Тщательно пропылесосить

2 - Нанести химию и немного подождать, пока она поработает

3 - Пройтись щеткой, чтобы поднять загрязнения

4 - Тщательно прополоскать сидение экстрактором с подачей воды

#химчисткасалона #химчисткасидений
```

Here's a little code I sketched out, I tried a lot of things, but they don't work, I ran out of ideas.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs


def _html_to_text(html) -> str:
    hrefs = []
    soup = bs(html, 'lxml')

    for x in soup.find_all():
        if len(x.get_text(strip=True)) == 0:
            x.extract()

    a_tags = soup.find_all('a', href=True)
    for a_tag in a_tags:
        href = a_tag.get('href')
        if href in hrefs:
            continue
        hrefs.append(href)
        a_tag.append(f' ({href})')

    return soup.get_text()
```

The output of this function is this:

```
 Процесс химчистки сидений:
1 - Тщательно пропылесосить
2 - Нанести химию и немного подождать, пока она поработает
3 - Пройтись щеткой, чтобы поднять загрязнения
4 - Тщательно прополоскать сидение экстрактором с подачей воды
#химчисткасалона #химчисткасидений
```

But the line breaks get knocked down, who knows how to solve the problem?)

Comment: The white spaces between tags/lines in the source are irrelevant/ignored in html. If you want blank lines between each text line you can add them afterwards

Comment: @buran I didn't think of that at first (Thank you!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out :)

```
def _html_to_text(html) -> str:
    hrefs = []
    html = html.replace('\n', '||')
    soup = bs(html, 'lxml')

    for x in soup.find_all():
        if len(x.get_text(strip=True)) == 0:
            x.extract()

    a_tags = soup.find_all('a', href=True)
    for a_tag in a_tags:
        href = a_tag.get('href')
        if href in hrefs:
            continue
        hrefs.append(href)
        a_tag.append(f' ({href})')

    text = soup.get_text()
    return text.replace('||', '\n')
```